# Apache kafka KTable aggregation ClassCastException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an apache kafka topic "historyTopic", connected with stream:

```
KStream<Long, byte[]> stream = builder.stream("historyTopic");
```

I also have a table associated with the stream:

```
KTable<Long, HistoryObject> table = stream.groupByKey().aggregate(() -> {
            return new HistoryObject();
        }, (key, value, aggregate) -> {
        try {
           aggregate.add(deserializeModel(value));
        } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return aggregate;
    }, Materialized.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer)).as("history-store"));
```

I expect value in the aggregation to be byte[] and aggregate variable to be object of HistoryObject class, In the initializer i first create a new object and in aggregation method i expect to deserialize the byte[] value and add it to the list in the aggregate ( HistoryObject ), but I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to com.maxflow.historyservice.model.HistoryObject
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamAggregate$KStreamAggregateProcessor.process(KStreamAggregate.java:91) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:302) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:409) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:964) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:832) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736) ~[kafka-streams-2.0.1.jar:na]
```

deserializeModel method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Card deserializeModel(byte[] serialized) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(serialized);
    ObjectInput in = null;
    Card  historyData = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        historyData = (Card) in.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        bis.close();
    }
    return historyData;
    }
```

In this method, I deserialize the byte[] from the stream into a Card object and after that I try to add it to the List from the HistoryObject

My serializer and deserializer classes look like this:

```
public class HistoryDataValueSerializer implements Closeable, AutoCloseable, Serializer<HistoryObject> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean isKey;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey)
    {
        this.isKey = isKey;
    }

    @Override public byte[] serialize(String arg0, HistoryObject value) {
        byte[] retVal = null;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
          retVal = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value).getBytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retVal;
      }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {

    }

  }


public class HistoryDataValueDeserializer implements Closeable, AutoCloseable, Deserializer<HistoryObject> {

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {

    }

    @Override
    public HistoryObject deserialize(String s, byte[] value) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    HistoryObject historyObject = null;
    try {
        historyObject =  mapper.readValue(value, HistoryObject.class);    
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return historyObject;
    }


    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

  }
```

Comment: What is your default key and value serde config  `DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG`and  `DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG`
?

Comment: streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass());
 streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray().getClass());

Comment: The main thing is that the KStream is <Long,byte[]> and KTable is <Long, HistoryObject> , they have different values, one is byte[] and another is History object, and when I produce my new byte[] with producer I want to deserialize it and add it to the History object so my state store remembers all the produced records for the specified key which is long. Is there another way to do this and am I on the right path?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. Did you try to debug with .aggregate() method?

Comment: Yes I did, It doesnt even reach the Initializer or Aggregator method, I'm thinking the problem might be with the KGroupedStream<Long, byte[]> ( which we get with stream.groupByKey() ) calling aggregate method and returning KTable<Long, HistoryObject> , but I'm not that good with kafka so don't know where the problem is, is it possible grouped stream with value byte[] to aggregate into HistoryObject ktable?

Comment: If I change my KTable to <Long, byte[]> everything works, but in that case the value will be single Card object and I dont want to store only a single card for every key, but collection of Card, which I do with the HistoryObject implementation and add() method, but I get the following exception

Comment: It seems, problem is with `Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer)`. Can you post the `serializer` and `deserializer` value?

Comment: I already posted them, it's: HistoryDataValueSerializer and HistoryDataValueDeserializer

Comment: Can you check (ie, debug) `KStreamAggregate.java:91` where the exception happens? What are the data types of the objects?